# Add Date filtering from fields in a subquery join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following query which gets row counts and then sums them to return a single value (aggregration is working perfectly as of now):

```
SELECT

'COUNTS',
SUM(G.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(H.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(J.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(M.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(P.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(S.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(V.ROW_COUNT)  +
SUM(Y.ROW_COUNT) 

FROM
PS_JOB F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM PS_GHS_HS_ANN_EXAM G GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) G
 ON   F.EMPLID = G.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = G.EMPL_RCD

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM      
FROM PS_GHS_HS_ANTINEO H GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) H
 ON   F.EMPLID = H.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = H.EMPL_RCD

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM 
FROM PS_GHS_HS_AUDIO J GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) J
 ON   F.EMPLID = J.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = J.EMPL_RCD 

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM 
FROM PS_GHS_HS_DOT M GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) M
 ON   F.EMPLID = M.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = M.EMPL_RCD

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM PS_GHS_HS_HAZMAT P GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) P
 ON   F.EMPLID = P.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = P.EMPL_RCD

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM PS_GHS_HS_PREPLACE S GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) S
 ON   F.EMPLID = S.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = S.EMPL_RCD

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM PS_GH_RESP_FIT V GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) V
 ON   F.EMPLID = V.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = V.EMPL_RCD

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM PS_GHS_HS_ASBESTOS Y GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) Y
 ON   F.EMPLID = Y.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = Y.EMPL_RCD

WHERE ( ( F.EFFDT = 
 (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB F_ED 
  WHERE F.EMPLID = F_ED.EMPLID 
  AND F.EMPL_RCD = F_ED.EMPL_RCD 
  AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND F.EFFSEQ = 
 (SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB F_ES 
  WHERE F.EMPLID = F_ES.EMPLID 
  AND F.EMPL_RCD = F_ES.EMPL_RCD 
  AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) ))
```

I would like to be able to add Date criteria to the WHERE clause on the main query for date fields (EXAM_DT) from each LEFT OUTER JOINed table (G.EXAM_DT, H.EXAM_DT, J.EXAM_DT, etc...), however it seems that because I am doing a subquery on the JOINS (to get correct count aggregation), SQL does not recognize these fields in the outer (main) query. Is there a way to use fields from the subqueries into the WHERE clause in the main query?

I tried adding the Date field as part of the Subquery's (example below):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EXAM_DT, COUNT (DISTINCT EMPLID)
AS ROW_COUNT FROM PS_GHS_HS_ANN_EXAM G GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EXAM_DT) G
 ON  F.EMPLID = G.EMPLID AND F.EMPL_RCD = G.EMPL_RCD
```

But then it throws off the counts when I run the entire query, so I am trying to avoid having to alter the fields selected / grouped by in the sub queries).

What are my options in order to be able to use the date fields? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is the original results (Total) from the below query (these are the accurate counts):

[image]

Alternatively, here is what each of those fields values are (that sum to 40):

[image]

Here are the results when I add in EXAM_DT to each subquery/join (using above logic I tried):

**Total:**

[image]

**Row Counts (Sum to 48):**

[image]

Sample data from all the tables:

**PS_GHS_HS_ANN_EXAM (9 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD     
 001          0        2018-04-17     ANN
 03           0        2018-04-03     ANN
 4586         0        2018-03-02     ANN
 4586         0        2018-03-26     ANN
 6719         0        2018-03-02     ANN
 2602         0        2018-03-01     ANN
 1351         0        2018-04-16     ANN
 1351         1        2018-04-16     ANN
 4657         0        2018-03-02     ANN
```

**PS_GHS_HS_ANTINEO (5 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD 
 9866         0        2018-04-11     ANE
 001          1        2018-04-17     ANE
 03           0        2018-04-03     ANE
 6051         0        2018-03-06     ANE
 2602         0        2018-03-08     ANE
```

**PS_GHS_HS_AUDIO (5 rows):**

```
 EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD 
  001         0         2018-03-28     AUD
  001         1         2018-04-17     AUD
  01          0         2018-03-14     AUD
  03          0         2018-04-03     AUD
  4586        0         2018-03-29     AUD
```

**PS_GHS_HS_DOT (3 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD
 001          1        2018-04-17      DOT
 5829         0        2018-04-03      DOT
 2602         0        2018-03-08      DOT
```

**PS_GHS_HS_HAZMAT (4 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD
 001          1        2018-04-17      HAZ
 001          1        2018-04-18      HAZ
 001          1        2018-05-14      HAZ
 2602         0        2018-03-01      HAZ
```

**PS_GHS_HS_PREPLACE (9 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD
 01           0        2018-03-20      PRE
 03           0        2018-04-02      PRE
 04           0        2018-04-04      PRE
 05           0        2018-04-03      PRE
 07           0        2018-04-04      PRE
 0285         0        2018-04-09      PRE
 1325         0        2018-04-09      PRE
 5272         0        2018-04-09      PRE
 4555         0        2018-04-06      PRE
```

**PS_GHS_HS_RESP_FIT (4 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD
 4299         0        2018-04-04      RSP
 3003         0        2018-04-02      RSP
 8908         0        2018-04-11      RSP
 2602         0        2018-04-04      RSP
```

**PS_GHS_HS_ASBESTOS (1 rows):**

```
EMPLID     EMPL_RCD     EXAM_DT     EXAM_TYPE_CD
 2602         0        2018-03-01      ASB
```

All the counts from the above tables total 40, and this is what I am getting in my original query. However the total is incorrect when adding in the Date select in each subquery.

EDIT 2:

**PS_JOB (Filtered for applicable EMPLID's):**

```
EMPLID      EMPL_RCD      EFFDT      EFFSEQ      PER_ORG
00000044       0       2018-04-05      0          CWR
001            0       2018-01-01      0          CWR
001            1       2018-03-16      0          EMP
01             0       2018-03-14      0          CWR
03             0       2018-02-26      0          CWR
03             1       2018-03-23      0          CWR
04             0       2018-03-21      0          CWR
04             0       2018-03-22      0          CWR
04             0       2018-03-22      1          CWR
05             0       2018-03-20      0          CWR
05             0       2018-03-22      0          CWR
55829          0       1987-08-10      0          EMP
07             0       2018-03-30      1          CWR
4299           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
0285           0       2017-07-01      0          EMP
1325           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
5272           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
6051           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
3003           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
4555           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
8908           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
2602           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
1351           0       2018-01-01      0          EMP
1351           1       2018-03-22      0          CWR
4657           0       2008-10-18      0          EMP
```

Comment: Please provide the result you are getting now along with your expected result

Comment: @DanielMarcus I edited the post and added results I am getting.

Comment: If you can provide sample data for me to work with I can fix the query for you

Comment: Also, please shown me how you attempted to add dates to the outer query filter

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I added in sample data from the joined tables. You should see my code example above where I attempted to add dates on the subqueries. On the outer queries, I simply added in the WHERE clause "AND G.EXAM_DT > '04-01-2018'). I get the error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')"

Comment: thanks very helpful - will get to it ASAP

Comment: Need data in table PSJob too

Comment: Why not add the where clause in the sub queries? `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM PS_GH_RESP_FIT V  WHERE EXAM_DT >= '20180401' GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) V`. I would parameterize this so you can change it on the fly

Comment: @DanielMarcus I added sample data above for PS_JOB as well. Appreciate it if you know a way to have this work! Thanks

Comment: @scsimon I am going to be saving this query as a SQL view, and the online query tool I will be putting this into can not natively input date parameters into subqueries. That's why I was hoping there is a way to use date criteria in the outer query.

Comment: why not a stored procedure so you can use parameter (views don't accept parameters, but I understand what you were trying to say)?

Comment: @DanielMarcus just curious if you had come up with anything? Appreciate the help!

Comment: sorry didnt get a chance - will try to get to it today

Comment: OK done see below and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this should work.  Remove # symbols and be careful of spelling (one table was misnamed)

```
select count(b.emplid)+
  count(c.emplid)+
  count(d.emplid)+
  count(e.emplid)+ 
  count(ff.emplid)+ 
  count(g.emplid)+ 
  count(h.emplid)+ 
  count(i.emplid)
   from #PS_JOB f 
  left join #PS_GHS_HS_ANN_EXAM b on f.EMPLID=b.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=b.EMPL_RCD
    left join #PS_GHS_HS_ANTINEO c on f.EMPLID=c.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=c.EMPL_RCD
      left join #PS_GHS_HS_AUDIO  d on f.EMPLID=d.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=d.EMPL_RCD
      left join #PS_GHS_HS_DOT  e on f.EMPLID=e.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=e.EMPL_RCD
        left join #PS_GHS_HS_HAZMAT ff on f.EMPLID=ff.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=ff.EMPL_RCD
        left join #PS_GHS_HS_PREPLACE g on f.EMPLID=g.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=g.EMPL_RCD
           left join #PS_GHS_HS_RESP_FIT h on f.EMPLID=h.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=h.EMPL_RCD
        left join #PS_GHS_HS_ASBESTOS i on f.EMPLID=i.EMPLID and f.EMPL_RCD=i.EMPL_RCD
        WHERE ( ( f.EFFDT = 
 (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM #PS_JOB F_ED 
  WHERE F.EMPLID = F_ED.EMPLID 
  AND F.EMPL_RCD = F_ED.EMPL_RCD 
  AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND f.EFFSEQ = 
 (SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM #PS_JOB F_ES 
  WHERE F.EMPLID = F_ES.EMPLID 
  AND F.EMPL_RCD = F_ES.EMPL_RCD 
  AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) ))
***and [ADD DATE FILTERS HERE]***
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try this when I have a moment.

Comment: Don't have a chance to run this yet. So this does the aggregation before the joins, and then I can still add in the aliased field name for EXAM_DT to filter on at the bottom?